# How do i resolve this HTML Doctype errors

Tags: html, doctype

this doctype doesn't support following attributes
produce errors on w3 validations
like
there is no attribute "type"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Comment: What is the exact validation error message? What attributes are you talking about? I don't see an attribute named "type". To cut a long story short: I don't understand your question.

Comment: You aren't providing enough information. If you are going with  XHTML 1.0 Transitional (Not sure why you're doing that), then you'll need to use the `<head>` tag which is missing. If you're getting a 'no attribute - type' error, then you haven't included anything that would produce that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that extra stuff. This should suffice without errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```